# How to load multiple category by id or name in magento2.3?

Tags: php, magento-2.3

Hi i want to load multiple category ids in magento 2.3.
I tried the code below, but it only fetches the 1st category of a subcategory, not the rest of the category.

```
$categories = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load(3,4,5);
```

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2 prohibits direct use of the `ObjectManager` (https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/object-manager.html).

You should use dependency injection to get a Resource Collection to query the categories, by injecting a `CollectionFactory` in your class constructor. This is a generated class, so you just need to type-hint it in the constructor parameters (you may need to run `bin/magento setup:di:compile` afterwards).

Example of a constructor with the type-hinted collection factory:

```
private $categoryCollectionFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory
) {
    $this->categoryCollectionFactory = $categoryCollectionFactory;
}
```

Then, in your method, you can get an instance of the resource collection and add the IDs to a filter, after which you can get the Category models.

```
public function someMethod()
{
    // get an instance of CategoryCollection
    $categoryCollection = $categoryCollectionFactory->create();

    // add a filter to get the IDs you need
    $categoryCollection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', [3, 4, 5]);

    // either call getItems() and iterate over it, or do whatever you need
    foreach ($categoryCollection->getItems() as $category) {
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor $category */

        // get the category data
        var_dump($category->getData());
    }
}
```